# Boolean Algebra: How does (x * z) + (!x * y) + (z * y) simplify to (x * z) + (!x * y)

Tags: boolean-algebra

How does the equation:

> (x * z) + (!x * y) + (z * y)

simplify to:

> (x * z) + (!x * y)

using boolean algebra?

I've been looking at the various theorems for quite awhile, but I can't figure out how this study guide I found online got to that answer.

Comment: You can expand the term $zy$ to $xzy+x'zy$, and then $xzy$ gets absorbed by $xz$ and the term $x'zy$ gets absorbed by $x'y$.  Also: this particular equivalence is called [the Consensus Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consensus_theorem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a possible transformation of one expression into the other one is not obvious, you can still blow up both expressions to their full disjunctive form:

$$xz + \bar x y + zy = x(y+\bar y)z + \bar xy(z+\bar z) + (x+\bar x)yz\\=xyz + x\bar yz + \bar xyz + \bar xy\bar z + xyz + \bar xyz\\ = xyz + \bar xyz + x\bar yz + \bar xy\bar z$$
and
$$xz + \bar xy = x(y+\bar y)z + \bar xy(z+\bar z)\\ = xyz + x\bar yz + \bar xyz + \bar xy\bar z$$

As both expressions are equal, you have now a transformation of one expression into the other one.

Comment: So other than taking a guess that (x * z) + (!x * y) is the right answer and then verifying after the fact, is there no way to get to (x * z) + (!x * y) from (x * y * z) + (!x * y * z) + (x * !y * z) + (!x * y * !z)  ?

Comment: Nevermind, I see how you can get to it now.  Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 0):

You can draw a truth table and compare the output of the two expressions.

Basically for $z = y$, both expressions will output $z$ ($=y$).

For $z = 1, y = 0$, both will output $x$.

For $z = 0, y = 1$, both will output $!x$.